# Look up type synonyms in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a way to look up what type synonyms actually mean? Is there perhaps some GHCi command that I can use to see if a given type is a synonym of something else?

Comment: Both [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) are great for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in GHCi you can use `:info`:

```
Prelude> :info String
type String = [Char]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
Prelude>
```

EDIT and more examples including a non-alias example:

```
Prelude> :info Rational
type Rational = GHC.Real.Ratio Integer  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
Prelude> :i Double
data Double = GHC.Types.D# GHC.Prim.Double#
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
```